# Wildcards in Flyway deploy scripts?

Tags: flyway

We are trying to use Flyway for SQL Server and have a question regarding wildcards in .sql scripts. When deploying to our Dev, TST, and Prod environments, we make use of sql server synonyms and linked servers that are env specific. For example, when deploying to TST, the Linked Server and Synonym will point to SERVER_A, but Prod should point to SERVER_B. Is there a way for Flyway to automatically swap in the correct SERVER value depending on which environment we are deploying to at release time?

Comment: Do you want to use configurable placeholders in sql-scripts? Provide more information about what you want to get step by step, please.